# angular copying style sheet from an external library

Tags: angular

I'm using the `ngx-json-viewer` external library for pretty json rendering and would like to copy some of the css classes to another part of my UI to create a visually consistent experience. Is there any way I can reference the library's stylesheet? Or would I have to copy the classes into my .scss file?

https://github.com/hivivo/ngx-json-viewer/blob/main/src/ngx-json-viewer/ngx-json-viewer.component.scss